# go: gopkg.in/ldap.v3@v3.1.3: parsing go.mod

Tags: go, ldap, go-modules, tidy

go: cannot find main module, but found Gopkg.lock in

```
C:\Users\<github>
    to create a module there, run:
    cd ..\..\.. && go mod init
```

I get the following error after executing **go mod init** and **go mod tidy**

```
go: gopkg.in/ldap.v3@v3.1.3: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3
                but was required as: gopkg.in/ldap.v3
```

My code only has imports for gopkg.in/ldap.v3 not sure which vendor module or package has import for github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3

Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

scenario 1: If you are using an old import path which was deprecated, you have to update your import path to github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3 in your go.mod

scenario 2: You may have an old import in your code! Refactor your code to the new import path.

For the first scenario:

```
go clean -modcache
go get github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3
go mod tidy
```